# How to model this case in a firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

New to cloud Firestore building a first flutter application. I have the following use case:

I'm building a game with Modes, Decks, and challenges. Each Mode can have separate decks, and each challenge is assigned a deck. e.g:

```
Mode A -> Deck 1,2,3 
Mode B -> Deck 4,5,6
Mode C -> Deck 7,8,9

Challenge 1 -> Deck 1
Challenge 2 -> Deck 2
Challenge x -> Deck 8
```

Should I use document references here, or is it better to add a field such as decknumber as an int to the Firestore collection?

Comment: We are usually structuring a Firestore database according to the queries that we want to perform. What are those queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo Possible queries would be: Select * from decks where modeNumber = ..., and Select * from challenges where deckNumber = ....

Comment: Are you going to randomly assign decks to modes and also decks to challenges or do you have some fixed algorithm to do that like for example Deck 2 is always assigned to challenge 2 and Deck 3 is assigned to Challenge 3 etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform the following queries:

> Select * from decks where modeNumber = ..., and Select * from challenges where deckNumber = ....

Then you should simply define two separate collections, one called "decks" and another one called "challenges". In the first collection, you should add documents that should contain a field called "modeNumber", of type number, and in the second one, you should add documents that should contain a field called "deckNumber", of type number as well. In code it should look like this:

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('decks').where("modeNumber", isEqualTo: value)
```

And

```
await Firestore.instance.collection('challenges').where("deckNumber", isEqualTo: value)
```

Comment: Perfect, I indeed went with this solution. Glad to know that this is how this should be doine. Thanksalot :)